# How can I set up Elastic Search's minimum_number_should_match within Tire?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I'm having a bit of trouble setting the minimum_number_should_match within my boolean query. I'm wondering how I can set that. Also, what is the default?

```
options = {:minimum_number_should_match => 1}

result = tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 20) do 
  query do 
    boolean do
      must {string squery, default_operator: "OR"} if squery.present?
      must {term :aasm_state, aasm_state }
      must {text :zipcode, zipcode} unless zipcode.nil?
      should {text :city, city} if city
      should {term :phone_store, true}
      should {term :email_store, true}
    end
  end 

  sort {by :created_at, 'desc' } if squery.blank?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass those options to the `boolean` method, see https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/235#issuecomment-3846598.